# Webpack exclude library from bundle

Tags: node.js, webpack, node-modules, bundle, webpack-5

I'm trying to bundle the project with webpack 5.
There is a problem with dynamic import, and I can't fix it, so I decided to exclude this library from the bundle, and then it works fine.
But, In the production version, I'm removing `node_modules` because it's running on lambda.

So here is a question: **Can we exclude library from bundle but use it without `node_modules`? If yes, how we can achieve this?**

For example, copy the library from `node_modules` to the `dist` folder and then change `import * from "library_name"` to point to the `import * from "./dist/library_name"` directory.